# MariaDB not allowing remote connections

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-server-2008, mariadb, navicat

[image]

[image]

As the screenshots show, I have the accounts setup to allow remote connections but as shown in the second screenshot I still cannot connect remotely.

Comment: Assuming that the credentials are fine, I would say a firewall is blocking you. Check the ports and ip's that are allowed to make connections(iptables in linux and unix-based os-es)

Comment: @AlexHristov Windows firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 37):

I use for testing in the virtual machine (Ubuntu 16.04), for me, I fixed the error changing the file `50-server.cnf`.

My server is Ubuntu, so changing the file below:

```
50-server.cnf
```

The path of this file:

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d
```

PS: Create a backup of the file before the change.

Only change in file the `bind-address 127.0.0.0` to `bind-address 0.0.0.0`

After this restart service and try again.

Regarding that user, need to allow for external connections.

I hope that this info helps you.

Comment: in my conf i don't have any bind-address and what it happens when i add that line, mariadb shows a bounch of alerts, please don't follow this recommendation

Answer (score 25):

Mysql by default binds to 0.0.0.0 which is all interfaces on your system. Which means you can already connect from another computer. The issue is perhaps permissions. You can enable remote connections by running the following command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: After just installing 10.1.34-MariaDB, I found that 127.0.0.1 is the default binding, so I had to change it from `bind-address          = 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address            = 0.0.0.0`. refer to LandiLeite's answer

Comment: i performed LandiLeite's then Fidel. In combination it works.

Answer (score 7):

MariaDB packages bind MariaDB to 127.0.0.1 (the loopback IP address) by default as a security measure using the bind-address configuration directive. Old MySQL packages sometimes disabled TCP/IP networking altogether using the skip-networking directive.

Steps to allow remote connections are provided in the MariaDB Knowledge Base at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/