# Mysql MariaDB is not working with remote connections

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I've been scratching my head for a day and probably read so many articles and on how can I allow my MariaDB to listen to remote connections. Unfortunately getting the below error.

```
Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server.
```

I also read this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server), [anotherQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664091/mariadb-not-allowing-remote-connections) and successfully able to create the new user and grant all permission with following MySQL query.

```
CREATE USER 'ahsensaeed'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ahsensaeed'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And below is my **ahsensaeed** user grants.

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show grants for 'ahsensaeed'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for ahsensaeed@%                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ahsensaeed'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F794ABE2A12665587C6B6D8B61E2F7E987711AFA' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the end, I just flush the privileges and after that, I go to my MariaDB configuration file and edit it. Below is the path where my MariaDB conf file placed.

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

The following shows my MariaDB file block.

```
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
.....
.....
```

and then I just restart the **mysql** service via /etc/init.d/mysql restart. I also open the 3306 port on my client for **mysql**.

When the above solution not works I also add the **bind-address = 0.0.0.0** in /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf file, but still it failed with error.

The following shows how I requesting for MariaDB database from my server.

> -> mysql -uahsensaeed -p -h hostIp

and then I got the below error.

> ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'hostIp' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

**Edit** Added the host and user data.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select User,Host from mysql.user;
+------------+-----------+
| User       | Host      |
+------------+-----------+
| ahsensaeed | %         |
| root       | localhost |
+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this "*F794ABE2A12665587C6B6D8B61E2F7E987711AFA" is not the password from 'my_password'

Comment: @BerndBuffen no this is only for the StackOverflow the actual password is **qwertyasdf**.

Comment: can you pls post the output from **SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE USER LIKE '%ahsensaeed%';**

Comment: @BerndBuffen added the output.

Comment: have you try **FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**

Comment: Yes, @BerndBuffen I try flush privileges after the **grant privileges** query.

Comment: A open MySQL/MariaDB port (3306) on the internet is considerd a security concern... Besides also posting a hashed MySQL password hash`*F794ABE2A12665587C6B6D8B61E2F7E987711AFA` which is (`qwe.tyas..`) on a online forum is a security concern.. So you should change your MySQL password.

Comment: Comment bind-address attribute in mysql.cnf file and restart the server.

Comment: What's the value of `skip_name_resolve`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (I`m using Ubuntu 18.04 as virtual machine and Windows 10 with Vagrant):

```
sudo mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE {db_name};"
sudo mysql -e "CREATE USER {user_name}@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '{password}';"
sudo mysql -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='%' WHERE User='{user_name}';"
sudo mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {db_name}.* TO '{user_name}'@'%';"
sudo mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

After that, you should edit the file:

> /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

And set **bind-address** property to your hostIP address or just comment this line out.

Finally, run commands:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

I hope this will suit your needs